# clear a form without refresh

Tags: php, jquery

am working with a form that has recaptcha and its validated with jquery, everything works perfectly fine *the info is sent to my email and all required field are checked before been send)

the only one problem am facing is that once the info is sent and all fields are reset the error messages are visible 
only way they are hidden is if page is i change in the js "reset" instated of "clear" but this refresh the pagge and the thank u message isnt visible anymore.

(i know maybe all sounds bit confiusing)
this is the code what am talking

```
function validateCaptcha(){
    challengeField = $("input#recaptcha_challenge_field").val();
    responseField = $("input#recaptcha_response_field").val();
    nameField = $("input#name").val();
    emailField = $("input#email").val();
    phoneField =$("input#phone").val();
    reasonField =$("input#reason").val();
    messageField =$("textarea#message").val();

    var html = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.recaptcha.php",
    data: "recaptcha_challenge_field=" + challengeField + "&recaptcha_response_field=" + responseField +"&name="+ nameField +"&email=" + emailField +"&phone="+ phoneField + "&reason=" + reasonField +"&message=" + messageField,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

    if(html == "success")
    {
        $('#contactForm').each (function(){
          this.reset();
         Recaptcha.reload();
        }) 

        $("#thanks").html("Thank you");


         return false;
    }

    else
    {
        $("#captchaStatus").html("Your captcha is incorrect. Please try again");
        Recaptcha.reload();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i really need it be just one button! is that possible to archive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a reset button to clear the form feilds.

```
<input type="reset" />
```

Comment: the only problem is that i dont want to add any other button

Comment: is possible to do it without show the reset button? i mean a way to do it with js? (am really new with js, so i really have no idea how to do it) do u know how? thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply add this:

```
$("#captchaStatus").html("");
```

right below:

```
$("#thanks").html("Thank you");
```

That should clear out your error message.